# semicolon in DNS name when nslookup resolving CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup

I am running two Win2k3 and one Win2k8 DNS servers (and AD) in the same domain, country1.company.com.
The DNS servers all have a secondary DNS zone for the AD domain country2.company.com. The two AD domains are configured such that they are NOT in the same forest.

As country2 is where many of the resources are in, I have CNAMES e.g. computerA.country1.company.com mapping to computerA.country2.company.com. In the country1 DNS mmc, it looks like:

```
computerA         Alias (CNAME)       computerA.country2.company.com
```

This works until suddenly I get nslookup like this:

```
> server 192.168.3.2
Default Server:  server1.country1.company.com
Address:  192.168.3.2

> computerA
Server:  server1.country1.company.com
Address:  192.168.3.2

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    computerA.country1.company.com;country2.company.com
Address:  67.215.65.132
```

The resolved IP is of course incorrect, returned by OpenDNS, which is our DNS forwarder.

What is happening here? What does the semicolon mean? How do I correct the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem is now corrected by someone else who claimed is a group policy issue, but I don't see how. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the exact nslookup command you issues, but from what I can see here, what ever you looked up has two answers, and nslookup has returned both of them, separated by a ;.

Comment: The commands shown in the question are the commands issued. i.e. nslookup <enter> server 192.168.3.2 <enter> computerA <enter>.